# How to measure the ACU (Azure Compute Unit) consumed during a performance evaluation?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring, azure-performancecounters

*Context:* We are trying to measure the performance of an application running under an ASP (Azure Service Plan), we are evaluating it under `P1V2` (refer the below image). We have 210 ACU available and by math it should be multiplied by 6/4 as per the scale up rule because can be observed from the resource count graph.

[image]
Scale Up Image Rule:
[image]
resource count graph
[image]

During the performance evaluation observed 90% CPU spike, is there a way to caluclate how much ACU has been utilized during the test ?

[image]

Have enabled App insight for it for not getting any much information.

Comment: You can create alerts for this. Try with it.